# How to access the information that a figure is open?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'd like to do a task while the matplotlib figure is open, I'm looking for something like this:

```py
while "figure is open instruction" True:
    i = 0
    p = 0
    av_p = 0
    for i in range(5):
        if abs(position[0] - 2) <=10**-2
            p = mass * np.sqrt(velocity[0][0]**2 + velocity[0][1]**2)
            av_p = (p+av_p)/i+1
print(av_p)
```

So I'm trying to get a set of data during a certain time, and once the time is over the getting process of data turns back on.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. As it stands, it's unclear what your question is, and what the problem with the presented code is. I presume it's how to get a "figure is open instruction"? Could you please [edit] the post to contain a question and **your effort to solve it**?

Comment: What do you mean by open? 1. Opened in a window? 2. Opened as an in-line image in Jupyter notebook? 3. Opened in a window but not focused on currently? 4. Figure was created and figure handle exists, however it was not shown? 5. Figure handle exists? 6. Figure handle exists but the child contents may/may not exist? Precisely you need to articulate with much more precision about what you mean by _“figure is open”_. It all depends on what you want to achieve and the environment where the code is/will run. In other words it needs more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to update a plot (real time), may I suggest using [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). Particularly, have a look in the examples, one of then show how to easily update the curve of a plot.

In any case, to check if a window is open, you can try something like this: [How to detect that an axis belong to a window that has been closed in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027608/how-to-detect-that-an-axis-belong-to-a-window-that-has-been-closed-in-matplotlib)

```
# defining on_close event
def on_close(event):
    event.canvas.figure.axes[0].has_been_closed = True

# ploting 
fig = plt.figure()
a = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', on_close)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.has_been_closed = False

ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])
plt.show()

if ax.has_been_closed:
    print('closed')
```

Then you can use `ax.has_been_closed` to check if window is closed. Note that you have to have at least one axis defined.